# how can I create a project with django on my Mac?

Tags: django

I install python and Django on mac with pip , but when I want start project with Django by this command i have message error :

```
macs-MacBook:desktop mac$ django-admin.py startproject blog
```

[image: error message]

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pytz' distribution was not
>   found and is required by Django

i try solve that with this command but i have same error :

```
sudo pip install -U djangorestframework
```

how  can i solve that and create project ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: pkg\_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'django==1.9.1' distribution was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257947/error-pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-the-django-1-9-1-distribution-was)

Comment: Do NOT do `sudo` for `pip`. Use `virtualenv` in the first place.

Comment: Was just about to write what Andrey said. Your problem is when you use sudo python 2.7 is used, just use virtualenv and install everything there.
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the pytz package.

If you are inside a virtualenv, run:

```
pip install pytz
```

otherwise run:

```
sudo pip install pytz
```

to install it globally.

It appears that you are not using a virtualenv.

**I would recommend creating a virtualenv, and reinstalling all packages inside it using pip, without sudo**

This will most likely solve this problem, as well as future problems you will encounter from a single global pip installation handling multiple project dependencies.

To create a virtualenv, run:

```
virtualenv ENV_NAME
```

This will create a folder `ENV_NAME` at the current directory. Now activate it:

```
source ENV_NAME/bin/activate
```

Once activated, you will be using the local python installation within the virtualenv folder. `pip` installation will be located within this folder as well. You can create a separate virtualenv for each of your projects.